# How to save date value in dd/mm/yyyy into excel from SSIS where TimeZone=Eastern in server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have an SSIS package, which I am running a Stored Procedure and save the resultset in a object type of variable (as temptable) in the control flow, and in the data flow I am using a script to retrieve data from the object type of variable saving the result set in an excel file.

Everything works well except the date column. It should be in dd/mm/yyyy format, however whatever I have tried I could not prevent it to be in m/d/yyyy format in the excel.

What I have tried are:

1- Added this to connectionstring of Excel ConnectionManager -> `Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0;Readonly=False` and `Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;Readonly=False`. Both did not work.

2- Added a Derived Column task, derived a new "DerivedMyDate" column as `STR`, `WSTR`, `Date`. Used this column to save the date value in the excel file, where type is set as `STR` and `DATE`. None of my trials worked.

3- Added Data Conversion task, tried all same things that I've tried in 2nd step, none worked.

4- Added a dummy first line in the excel, where the data column is like `15/01/1900`. Does not work, it is adding the other rows below where date values in `m/d/yyyy` format.

Checked those pages, the answers did not work for me:
[Date format problem using SSIS for Excel into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043483/date-format-problem-using-ssis-for-excel-into-sql-server)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7e34a0af-a744-4a51-b925-3284d0fba296/problem-in-date-format-while-exporting-to-excel-destination-from-flat-file-source-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices

TimeZone of my PC: (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada), changing this is not an option.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not create a template xlsx file, with all the columns with the correct formatting, and then export to that instead? *(You may want to copy the file first to a different name, if you are generating dynamically named files.)*

Comment: i did, even there is a dummy row in the template xlsx. Still, a value with date (row[mydate].tostring()) is saved as "date" in the excel when new rows are added, instead of "custom dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: Pass the value as a date, not as a formatted string. Like I said, make sure the **column** has the formatting (not the top row, that's not useful for row 3 onwards).

Comment: All ye who pass here give up all hope.... or run excel specific code afterwards in a script task that opens the excel file and formats the column afterwards. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093071/format-excel-destination-column-in-ssis-script-task if at all possible, _avoid_ using excel as any kind of data interchange or report format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to propose a little modify a T-SQL query in a next solution for you.
At the step of extracting data from the Stored Procedure, if this one returns not many columns, you should declare a *table variable* with a names, types and columns count appropriated with your stored procedure columns, for example `@var`. Then you need to pass executed stored prococedure result in variable,

```
INSERT INTO @VAR
EXEC sp_your_stored_prodedure
```

At the last step you should retrieve data not from stored  procedure, but from `@var`, and to add in the select statement new field with `CONVERT` T-SQL function with date format 103 :

```
SELECT
      v.*
      ,CONVERT (NVARCHAR, v.date_field, 103) as target_date_format
FROM @var AS v
```

After this, you may work with this DataFlow and Date in the appropriate format.

Comment: After adding a new field in nvarchar format, I got this value using tostring() in my script (Data flow) and saved it to a WSTR type of field. Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a n older topic, I would like to share my experience and solution, it might help someone.

In my case I read my data from source SQL Table, then export it into Excel file using my SSIS package. It is showing in this format 2023-12-07 but I want it to be in format 12/07/2023.

for this purpose, in my SP/Sql script I extract the data formatted in my desired format using below query:

```
select format([DOB],'MM/dd/yyyy') as DOB from src_table
```

Then in my SSIS package, OLEDB_Source, I change the column type to:

[Output Column Data Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB4tx.png)

This fixed my issue.